# Can models give up their Vengeance move to recover from Knocked Down?

Tags: warmachine, hordes

I have a unit of **Troll Fennblades**.  On my opponent's turn, they are attacked, and many are killed.  Some make a `Tough` roll, though, and so are merely `Knocked Down`.  In my next `Maintenance Phase`, all of the **Fennblades** are entitled to `Vengeance`, which allows them to advance 3" and attack.  Can they give up that 3" move to remove `Knocked Down`?

Answer (score 5):

[According to Privateer Press Infernals](http://privateerpressforums.com/showthread.php?109675-Knocked-Down-amp-Vengeance&p=1468153#post1468153):

> **No.** While knocked down, a model cannot advance. A model cannot
>   sacrifice movement/action to stand until the start of its activation,
>   which is well after the Maintenance and Control phases.